# replace all non zero numbers in certain dataframe columns with 1

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change all none-zero integers in the dataframe to `1`

the data
[image]

I tried `data.iloc[, 2:]!= 0` and received boolean values as result.
How can I replace all non-zero values to `1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
data.iloc[, 2:] = data.iloc[, 2:].mask(data.iloc[, 2:]!= 0, 1)
```

Or if exist only positive values use [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
data.iloc[, 2:] = data.iloc[, 2:].clip(upper=1)
```